# Are local variables not accessible within generator functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm learning Python and ran this piece of code in the python console earlier today:

```
num = 0

def generator():
    while True:
        yield num
        num += 1

for i in generator():
    if i > 5: break
    print(i)
```

It threw a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment`

I re-wrote the code and this version worked:

```
def generator():
    num = 0
    while True:
        yield num
        num += 1

for i in generator():
    if i > 5: break
    print(i)
```

My question is this: Can you not use local variables inside generator functions like you can with regular functions?

Comment: `num` is not local to your function in the failing code

Comment: @UnholySheep if I define a function, `test()` with `print(num)` inside it and call `test()` in the console, it prints out 0.

Comment: @Vinayak from the accepted answer of the linked question: "If you want to simply access a global variable you just use its name. However to change its value you need to use the global keyword."

Comment: @Vinayak if your `test()` function were to do `num += 1` you would get the same error (see the question @Mephy linked)

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with generator functions.  If you remove the `yield` from your first example, you'll see the same error.

Comment: @Mephy that explains it. Thank you!

Comment: @Vinayak - Consider accepting one of the given answers, even if the comments were clear enough.

Comment: @linusg Done. I was waiting for the time limit before I could accept answers to expire.

Comment: Ah I see :). One needs to wait too long sometimes IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code, you attempt to use num as a global variable: It is defined outside the function.

When the program reaches `num += 1`, you then attempt to assign to a local variable which happens to have the same name as the global that you referenced earlier. But since a local variable called num hasn't be assigned a value yet, the increment fails.

If you want to assign or increment a global variable inside a function, it must be declared with `global num` (usually right at the start of the function). This has nothing to do with generators, it would fail for regular functions too.

Answer (score 1):

As [UnholySheep has commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430360/are-local-variables-not-accessible-within-generator-functions/39430405#comment66184089_39430360), the `num` variable is not locally defined inside the `generator()` function.

Just mark that you use it from the global namespace inside the `generator()` function, using the `global` keyword:

```
num = 0

def generator():
    global num
    while True:
        yield num
        num += 1

for i in generator():
    if i > 5: break
    print(i)
```

...and everything should be fine.

**Note:** The issue is not related to the type of function (generator including `yield`) you're using.